# In recursive make, prevent -j from cascading down

Tags: gnu-make

I have a top-level makefile which specifies -jn for parallel build. This top level makefile calls many different component makefiles. Different components come from different repositories, and some of them support parallel build, while others do not. I could specify -j1 at the top level to make all components to work. But is there a way to specify -jn at the top level, let the flag cascade down to some components, but enforce -j1 for other components? If I use NOTPARALLEL phony target in selected lower-level makefiles, will that enforce -j1 only for those components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use NOTPARALLEL phony target in selected lower-level makefiles, will that enforce -j1 only for those components?

Yes. From GNU Make Special Targets page:

> **.NOTPARALLEL**
>
> If .NOTPARALLEL is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of make will be run serially, even if the ‘-j’ option is given. Any recursively invoked make command will still run recipes in parallel (unless its makefile also contains this target)

It's worth mentioning that for those pesky 3rd-party libraries that don't set .NOTPARALLEL themselves properly there is a way to do it by passing multiple files the the recursive make command:

1. Create a file with content ".NOTPARALLEL", e.g. notparallel.mk
2. In the recipe for making the library, do `$(MAKE) -f lib.mk -f notparallel.mk`

That'll ensure .NOTPARALLEL is mentioned as a target for that make invocation, without you modifying that library per se.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the single line

```
.NOTPARALLEL:
```

in it, say `notparallel.mk` like Andreas proposed. Then however, don't simply include it in the call to the first sub-makefile for the parallelism problem will resurface with the next level of subsub-makefiles being called by this makefile. Instead add it to the special variable `MAKEFILES` which contains the list of makefiles which will be included automatically with every invocation of `make` from there on:

```
MAKEFILES += notparallel.mk

maintarget:
      $(MAKE) -f sub-makefile.mk
```

Comment: I admit using the MAKEFILES variable is a better solution for enforcing .NOTPARALLEL throughout a 3rd party library build system

Comment: @Andreas no problem, after a few awkward race conditions the question author will come back to this solution too, I suppose ;)