# Running parallel builds using GNUmake

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

We are supporting two modes of builds (32 & 64 bit). For that we are having two targets:

For 32 bit we have `make32`

For 64 bit we have `make64`

Whenever user try to run `make` command with `make32`, It will run `32bit` build and same way for with `make64` it will run `64bit` build. We have another target called `makeboth` which runs both 32 & 64 bit builds sequentially.

```
makeboth:
         $(MAKE) make32 
         $(MAKE) make64
```

Above make snippet is in top level GNUmakefile, where we are running several makefiles inside its child directories. I want to run both 32 & 64 bit builds in parallel when user passes target `makeboth`.Is it possible to do that ? Can anyone one please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange it so that `makeboth` has the other two as prerequisites.

```
makeboth: make32 make64
    @echo makeboth done
```

Then `make -jN makeboth` should do the parallel build.

Comment: Kayulum, can we have any number with -j<number> or we have any restriction based on some criteria/load?

Comment: @naga I usually use a little less than the number of cores on my system. See also: [What's best value for make -j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025587/whats-best-value-for-make-j)

Comment: Thanks Kaylim, I have one doubt , Here if we pass -j<some_number> ,parallel execution should be applied for all targets in our GNUmakefile? or only with the target that we pass i.e. makeboth (only pre-reqs of makeboth run parallel.)

Comment: It will run as much of the build as possible in parallel. That is, `make` will work out which targets are independent and will run those in parallel.

Comment: Nice...Then it is applicable for all the targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-j N` option to run targets in parallel:

```
makeboth: make32wrapper make64wrapper;
    @echo makeboth done

# We need wrappers here to prevent parallel execution deeper in the
# make32 and make64 targets
make32wrapper:
    @$(MAKE) -s make32
make64wrapper:
    @$(MAKE) -s make64

make32:
    echo make32 started
    sleep 3
    echo make32 done

make64:
    echo make64 started
    sleep 3
    echo make64 done
```

Example:

```
$ make -j 10 makeboth
make32 started
make64 started
make64 done
make32 done
makeboth done
```

Comment: Doj, Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate why do we need wrappers here? And also what does -s option do? How can we add checks in GNUmakefile that user has passed with -j <int> and proceed with parallel build?

Comment: 1. Necessity of the wrappers depends on how make32 and make64 and their prerequisites implemented. If they are implemented in a way that they allow parallel execution, we don't need the wrappers here. In general case they may work incorrect in parralel, so its just for safity.

Comment: 2. `-s` means 'silent' for submakes and I added it here just for nice-looking output in the example code :)

Comment: 3. `-j N` is native option for GNU make. To check inside Makefile code if it was specified you can try to use `$(MAKEFLAGS)` variable.

Comment: okay as per your 1st point, i understood that we run only make32 , make64 targets parallely and not the targets that depends on them right ? In our implementation the pre reqs which are dependent on make32/64 is not running parallel. So i guess we need to have wrappers right... Below answer posted by kaylum also works for me right? Is there any drawbacks with the same?

Comment: You understood it right. See also this answer for another possible approach: [In recursive make, prevent -j from cascading down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270487/11695625)

Comment: Actually i wanted to run as much of the build as possible in parallel. if we have wrappers it wont work for all targets. so I guess  kaylum's answer will suit my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

GNUmake enables you to run two commands concurrently, using the -j argument of make:

you can dod this manulay via command line:

where N is the process numbers to be spawned

```
make -j <N> make32 make64
```

This command will run the two commands/targets simultaneously. you can even do better by creating a new make target that handles this. Back in the Makefile:

supply number in the `N` section !

```
makeboth:
    make -j <N> make32 make64
```